# How can I check if a PDF has active content with Python?

Tags: python, pdf

Active contents are JavaScript, PostScript. I want to know for a given PDF file if it contains any active content. How can I check this with Python?

Comment: To the one person who put a close vote here: How can this be more focused? Should I add a specific Python version? Go through all Python libraries + raw python and ask how to do it with them (resulting in maybe 10 super similar questions)? Please elaborate where you think this is vague.

Comment: Do you know what PDF *objects* are responsible for these content types? Check Adobe's manual. Then go through the various PDF libraries and find out if they allow access to these objects – standard operations will be wrapped in functions, you may have to use low level access.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Python library that gives access to what Adobe (and some other libraries) calls the COS level. That's the level of objects in the file.

For JavaScript I'm afraid there is no other way than to go through the PDF specification, and look for all places where JavaScript would be allowed, and then check those.

For PostScript I was going to say you don't have to be concerned about that because it's no longer possible, but I have to come back on that view :) You basically need to check for:

- PostScript XObjects: I'm a bit surprised that these are still in the specification because I thought they were deprecated, but oh well, at least in 32000-1 they apparently still exist.
- PostScript functions (Type 4 functions). Some PDF objects use functions in their definitions and there is a PostScript function type.

Then it becomes a bit tricky as there are some caveats:

- At one point there was a PostScript operator that could be used in the page stream and that could inject PostScript directly into the page stream. This *is* deprecated, but depending on your goal you might still have to detect it.
- When I said you need a library with COS level access, you might actually need more. You can detect a PostScript XObject on the COS level, but in order to know whether it's actually used on the page, you'll need a library that can also parse the page content for you. Whether you need this or not is up to your purpose.

And then, again depending on your purpose, you should realise that PostScript or JavaScript code could be hidden in stream objects just about anywhere in a PDF file. They wouldn't be used because tools wouldn't know it's there, but they would still be there. Whether or not you're concerned about that depends on what you're planning to use this for.